# How to programmatically add a button that animates from 0 opacity to full opacity

Tags: xcode, opacity

I have to try to add a button that animates from 0 opacity to full opacity programmatically on the main view. What would be the coding for this? I was given this coding but can't seem to make it work.

```
[UIElement setAlpha: 0.0f]; 

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

[UIElement setAlpha: 1.0f]; 

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: hm in wich language are you coding?
i guess C,C++ or Objective-C because of the Xcode Tag.

Comment: Yea thats the thing I don't UIElement isn't even a thing lol 
Im coding in XCODE 4

Comment: XCode is a Developing Environment and no Language as far as i know o.O

Comment: Sorry. Its a tab application so objective c

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your viewDidLoad method:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,50);
btn.alpha = 0;
[self.view addSubview:btn];

[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.3
                 animations: ^(void) { btn.alpha = 1; } ];
```

Comment: ok the button shows up but it doesn't animate from 0 - 100% opacity

Comment: Increase the animation duration to 1.0, so you'll have time to see the change. Or put this code in the viewDidAppear method.

Comment: @MikeRyanTåndy if my answer helped you, you might want to consider accepting it as the correct answer.